# Files copied with cp are disappearing or not arriving as expected

Tags: command-line, files, macos

I'm trying to copy `~/Desktop/profiles/a.mobileprovision` to `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`. Whether or not that's a good idea is not the topic of this question. The files never appear, even when doing an `ls -la`. Here's my procedure.

1. `$ cd ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` // `cd` is working as expected.
2. `$ cp ~/Desktop/profiles/a.mobileprovision .`
3. `$ find . -name "a.mobileprovision"`

nothing.

Permissions for the directory: `drwxr-xr-x`, so I should be allowed.

I'm on a Mac (Monterey 12.5), so I've also tried:

1. Opening up `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` in Finder and dragging and dropping `a.mobileprovision`, but it disappears upon releasing the mouse. I've got hidden files showing. No luck.
2. Copying `a.mobileprovision` to `~/Library/MobileDevice`. This works fine, but when I try to copy it to `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`, it does not.

**Responses to comments:**

3. Doing `$ pwd` after the `cd` yields `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`
4. Doing `$ cp ~/Desktop/profiles/a.mobileprovision ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` has the same effect: no copy performed.
5. Mac version: Monterey 12.5 (switched to bash from zsh).
6. `$ cp -v ~/Desktop/profiles/a.mobileprovision .` yields `~/Desktop/profiles/a.mobileprovision -> ./a.mobileprovision`
7. `find . -name "<file_already_in_dir>"` while in `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` is working.
8. Tried `cp ~/Desktop/profiles/a.mobileprovision ~/Library/MobileDevice/'Provisioning Profiles'`. Same problem.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: After step 1, type the command `pwd` and see if you are actually in the folder `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` or in a folder named `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning`?

Comment: @SottoVoce Yes, the cd to `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` worked.

Comment: @Peregrino69 No, that has the same effect. Not sure why.

Comment: Can you add `-v` to the command to see if that sheds any light? Or even `rsync -v ~/Desktop/profiles/a.mobileprovision ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles`.

Comment: @Peregrino69 cool, added. Thanks!

Comment: @doneal24 Added to the post. Thanks!

Comment: @Peregrino69 In `bash`, `~` is not expanded inside of single and double quotes. Either the full path the directory would have to be used and quoted or the space would have to be escaped with a backslash.

Comment: @Peregrino69 I didn't include that earlier but that method also works.

Comment: @Peregrino69 same issue. This is weird, right?

Answer (score 1):

Based purely on the text in your question, I suspect you created the target directory like this:

```
mkdir ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles
```

and then copied the file like this

```
cd ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles
cp ~/Desktop/profiles/a.mobileprovision .
```

What this has done, though, is not copy `a.mobileprovision` to `Provisioning Profiles`. Rather, it's attempted to copy `a.mobileprovision` and the directory `Provisioning` to the directory `Profiles` in the current directory.

The reason for this is that you haven't escaped the space in `Provisioning Profiles` so it is split into two words and treated as such: `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning` and `Profiles`. (The `cd` command in some shells ignores unexpected arguments - so in your case it will have actioned `cd ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning` and ignored the second word, `Profiles`.)

You have then told the system to copy `~/Desktop/profiles/a.mobileprovision` to the current directory (i.e. `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning`). This copy will have succeeded but you'll find it in the unintended `Provisioning` directory.

File and directory names that contain spaces *must* be quoted (or the spaces escaped with a backslash prefix (`\` ).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Two points: the Provisioning Profile dir is created by Apple when you download Xcode, so the name comes from them, and it does not include a backslash. Second, how do you account for the drag/drop with the GUI having the same result? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @h.and.h. The directory name doesn't include a backslash, but to reference it from a shell you need to quote the name or escape the space with a backslash. Otherwise syntactically `Provisioning Profile` is the same as `item1 item2`

Comment: Hello. Thanks again for your help. I completely agree: that's why I've addressed that point in the edit from the original post. I'm still not seeing the cp'd files. :/